# How does a windows phone detect if a headset is plugged

Tags: audio, windows-phone-8

I am developing a windows Phone application which is supposed to send audio signals to a circuitry. The circuit sends signals to another device on receiving the audio signal from windows phone. this works fine when connected to the audio jack of a laptop/pc, but windows phone does not detect this device to be a headset and it plays the audio signals through the loudspeaker. Is there any way to force the signals through the audio port?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way on Windows Phone to force the audio output channel. So the question that you should ask yourself is: why isn't your circuitry recognized as a headset? Which is probably more about electronics than programming. Jacks for phones have more connectors than ordinary jacks, though they're supposed to be retrocompatible: https://technosyndicate.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/122312_0549_common35mm11.png

Comment: I had problem as phones check this with impendence and laptop checks with a manual switch